# Android - ImageView picture size

Tags: android, imageview

Iam just starting to develope my first android app and actually Iam a bit confused about the ImageView container size. For example I've the following ImageView:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/image01" />
```

My Image is 300px * 300px (for xxhdpi). But when I import my image to this imageview...the image gets much smaller then expected. Do I have to add some settings to my imageview so that my image will fit the whole container (without scaling)? Cause if I understood correctly 100dp should be 300px.

Answer (score 0):

The default scale type for image view is fit_center. So try changing the scale type to the one that suits your need.